# webpack Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm going to start using react with babel with webpack but after run `webpack -w` it's not working and showing a error like

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'
```

my webpack config

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/components/Main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "public/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: "babel-loader"
        }
    }
}
```

my Main.js react file

```js
var React = require('react');

var Main = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                Hello world!
            </div>
        )
    }
});

React.render(<Main />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Please can anyone resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

we should specify an array of loaders for loaders objects

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./app/components/Main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "public/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loaders: ["babel-loader"],
            }
      ],
    },

};
```

Comment: yep, but I need to wait 17 hours